# Can webpack expose a var from the top level of a vanilla js file?

Tags: webpack

I want to use the var from a javascript file structured like this...

```
var thing = 123;
```

I added the repo with the file like `yarn add git://repo` and I need to access `thing` in my webpack-built project. How can I configure webpack to expose `thing` to the rest of my code?

This seems like the way to expose `thing` if this webpack.config.js file was in the module...

```
module.exports = {
   ...
   entry: './js/index.js',
   output: {
      path: './www/js/',
      filename: 'index.js',
      library: 'myLibrary',
      libraryTarget: 'var'
   ...
}
```

...but I'm not writing the module. I just want to access the var from inside some random js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `exports-loader`.

After adding the repo with yarn, the folder is in `node_modules/`. Add `exports-loader` with

```
yarn add exports-loader
```

and add a rule to webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve(
          "./node_modules/repo-name/vanilla-file.js"
        ),
        use: "exports-loader?thing"
      },
...
```

After build, the var `thing` is available from files in src/ by doing this:

```
import thing from "../node_modules/repo-name/vanilla-file";
```